# How to "reset" a postgres database on PythonAnywhere?

Tags: postgresql, pythonanywhere

After some testing with Django on PythonAnywhere, I want to get rid of my testing data before I import my actual data to the postgres database. I thought the best way would be to start from scratch and "reset" somehow the database.

Unfortunately there is no button for that on pythonanywhere.com and the [documentation](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Postgres/) does not say anything.

So the question is: how can I "reset" or empty the postgres database on PythonAnywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the PythonAnywhere support I found a way which worked for me: I deleted and re-created my database (called my_db_name) as follows:

Open a bash console (not a virtualenv console!) and execute the following commands:

```
dropdb -h xxx.postgres.eu.pythonanywhere-services.com -p 10077 -U super my_db_name
createdb -h xxx.postgres.eu.pythonanywhere-services.com -p 10077 -U super my_db_name
```

(replace above `xxx` with your data)